# How to detect Polyline touches? - Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: sdk, maps, touch, polyline, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am looking at adding Routes to my App. I was wondering how can I detect a touch on a GMSPoyline? I am using version 1.1.2 of the Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.0 has been released and it looks like it's now possible.  "Non-marker overlay types are tappable (see GMSMapViewDelegate)."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases